# Broken pipe at client on TCP connection to server inside docker on Mac OS using Python

Tags: python, sockets, docker, tcp

I have a client.py sending data to (server_ip,60000). The server side code, which receives data, sits inside a docker container. The codes are in Python and the server runs on Mac OS. Before migrating to docker, I could successfully transmit data. After dockerizing the server.py code, the bind happens, but client.py at `connection.sendall(out)` says:

```
socket.error: [Errno 32] Broken pipe
```

Here is my docker-compose.yml:

```
version: '2'
services:
  server:
    build: ./server
    ports:
      - server_IP:60000:60000
```

and here is the binding inside server.py:

```
port = 60000                   
host = "localhost"
```

Any idea why this happens?

Answer (score 1):

Well, I could fix it by setting the host at server side to 0.0.0.0 inside docker and removing-rebuilding the image. All works fine.

Comment: Yep, it seems that connections from outside of docker are not "local" for the docker-based server!